# Make background-page visible in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a `background-page` in my Google Chrome extension, and this page is naturally invisible. Is there anyway to make this hidden page visible, say in a popup when a browser action icon is clicked? Then hide it again with another click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The background page can be shown using the [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create) method, which requires the [`tabs` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/). For example, if your background page is called `background.html`, the following code can be used:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')});
```

See also:

- [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create)
- [Manifest permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/)
- [`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL)

Comment: Will the background page in the new tab be the same page as the one invisible in the background, or will another instance of the page be opened, while the invisible background page remains invisible?

Comment: @Nyxynyx It is a new instance of `background.html`. You will see two `background.html` links at the `Active views` section. Also, `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()==window` is `false`. There is **no** way to show a hidden active background page. You can use the link at the extension, which shows the Developer tools for the background page. In this screen, all features (including the live DOM inspector) are available.

Comment: Thanks that developer tools for the background page really helps! Guess thats the closest that I can go to seeing the page for debugging purposes.

Comment: @RobW, window.alert and prompt on background page works.. is this expected behavior?

Comment: @Pacerier. Yes, in Chrome it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `backround_page` in a `browserAction` [popup](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#popups). It will however be a new instance of the `background_page`. One as the popup while it is open and the long lived invisible one in the background.

Answer (score 0):

In your extensions' popup page, add a piece of JS that utilities [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage). Give the `<html>` element of your background page an `id`, and use `window.getElementById("myBackgroundPageHTMLElementId")`

For Example, your callback could look like this:

```
document.getElementById("myPopupHTMLElementId").outerHTML = backgroundWindow.getElementById("myBackgroundPageHTMLElementId").outerHTML
```

After this JS script completes, the HTML element of your popup page will be ENTIRELY replaced with the background page (until you reload it)! This means all attributes, even on the HTML element are set to the background page's version.

Hope this helps!